# Axios multipart request by PUT method

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to make a put multipart request but it is calling POST even though I tried setting the method to "PUT"

```
config = {..., method:"PUT"}
axios.request("/getAll", formData, config)
```

Also, I have a confusion regarding two methods of Axios

***Axios.request() and Axios.get()***

What is the difference when we call request with method set to GET in config while calling axios.request() and directly calling axios.get()?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.request` takes only 1 argument: [config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config). So you should use:

```
axios.request({ url: '/getAll', method: 'put', data: formData })
```

`axios.get`, `axios.put` etc are aliases for requests, so you just write less code, because you don't need to specify request's type

```
axios.put('/getAll', formData)
```

**As a summary**, there is no difference between:

```
axios.request({ url: '/getAll', method: 'get' })
```

and

```
axios.get('/getAll')
```

The second option is just easier and cleaner.